# How to get Interactive Report attributes in excel file

Tags: oracle, plsql, printing, oracle-apex

I have an Interactive report which has no data in it and the No data found message is provided. I need to get the value in that attribute in my excel report generated through Apex Office Print.

I am using a PLSQL procedure to generate the report using static IDs. The procedure is similar to `AOP_SAMPLE3_PKG.SCHEDULE_AOP_API3_PKG` procedure.

My current template is as follows:

```
IR Title
{&interactive_1}

IR Title
{&interactive_2}
...
```

If its not possible to get the attribute value, is there any other way to include a comment at the end of each IR saying 'No data Available' only when no rows are returned.

Apex Version: 5.1.3.00.05
AOP Version: 3.0

**EDIT**
Apex Version: 18.1 (Recently updated)

Answer (score 0):

You can use so called angular expression. You template would be something like this:

```
IR Title
{&interactive_1} | {#aopireportdata_1.length == 0}No Data Found |{/aopireportdata_1.length == 0}

IR Title
{&interactive_2} | {#aopireportdata_2.length == 0}No Data Found |{/aopireportdata_2.length == 0}
```

Above | represents a new column.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am unable to test it at the moment due to some other db issues. I will make an update once I manage to test it.

Comment: Hi @standan, This solution doesn't seem to work as the comment gets printed even when there is data.

Comment: I can't find a reference to aopireportdata.length property in the [docs](https://www.apexofficeprint.com/docs/). Can you please provide a reference?